# (PHP+MySQL)Always gives server error at the 65th record

Tags: php, mysql

I am currently writing a simple php script to allow it to read a log file and put the data into a MySQL database. During which, it also makes web requests to a site to give me some data, which is also being inserted into the MySQL database. I should expect it to insert 500 records, then redirect me to my homepage, but however, it always ends up in server error and when I check the database, it only enters about 65-70 records only. I've checked, and there is no problem with the log file, as the script works with smaller number of records e.g. 60. Please help.

```
<?php
//Make a connection
$connection = mysql_connect("localhost:3306", "root", "XXXXXXXX");

//Select a table
$db_select = mysql_select_db("major_project", $connection);

//open file
$report = fopen('C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Apache2.2\htdocs\HN.F\report.txt', 'r') or exit("Unable to open report.txt");

//insert operation
while(!feof($report))
{
    $array = explode("\t", fgets($report));

    list($seg, $ts, $rule, $sev, $ref, $ref2, $source, $sourcep, $dest, $destp, $ser) = $array;

    if($seg != 'Segment')
    {
        if(count($array) == 12)
        {
            list($seg, $ts, $rule, $sev, $ref, $ref2, $source, $sourcep, $dest, $destp, $ser) = $array;
            $ipaddrloc = fopen('http://freegeoip.appspot.com/json/'.$source, 'r');
            while(!feof($ipaddrloc))
            {
                $var = fgets($ipaddrloc);
                $lat = json_decode($var)->latitude;
                $long = json_decode($var)->longitude;
                $country = json_decode($var)->countryname;
                $city = json_decode($var)->city;
            }   
            mysql_query("INSERT INTO `major_project`.`logs` (`LOG_NUMBER`, `Segment`, `Timestamp`, `Rule`, `Severity`, `Reference&nbsp;system`, `Reference`, `Source`, `Source port`, `Dest.`, `Dest. port`, `Service`, `Country`, `City`, `Latitude`, `Longitude`) VALUES (null, '$seg', '$ts', '$rule', '$sev', '$ref', '$ref2', '$source', '$sourcep', '$dest', '$destp', '$ser', '$country', '$city', '$lat', '$long')");
        }
        else
        {
            list($seg, $ts, $rule, $sev, $ref, $ref2, $source, $sourcep, $flag, $dest, $destp, $ser) = $array;
            $ipaddrloc = fopen('http://freegeoip.appspot.com/json/'.$source, 'r');
            while(!feof($ipaddrloc))
            {
                $var = fgets($ipaddrloc);
                $lat = json_decode($var)->latitude;
                $long = json_decode($var)->longitude;
                $country = json_decode($var)->countryname;
                $city = json_decode($var)->city;
            }   
            mysql_query("INSERT INTO `major_project`.`logs` (`LOG_NUMBER`, `Segment`, `Timestamp`, `Rule`, `Severity`, `Reference&nbsp;system`, `Reference`, `Source`, `Source port`, `Flag`, `Dest.`, `Dest. port`, `Service`, `Country`, `City`, `Latitude`, `Longitude`) VALUES (null, '$seg', '$ts', '$rule', '$sev', '$ref', '$ref2', '$source', '$sourcep', '$flag', '$dest', '$destp', '$ser', '$country', '$city', '$lat', '$long')");
        }
    }
}
header("Location: startpage.html");
```

?>

Comment: it would be more useful to paste the error than your code

Comment: If you get a 500, there is an `error.log` somewhere that may tell you more. Do you have access to that?

Comment: But I'm pretty sure you're simply hitting some request limit on Appspot's end. Does it work if you remove that request?

Comment: Do you have access to an error log file where a more detailed description of the error should be written to (e.g. /var/log/apache2/error.log)? Also check that allow_url_fopen is enabled in php.ini or use an alternative way to get the contents from the webservice. Btw. doesn't need fopen an according fclose to avoid leak of handles?

Comment: hmm im quite sure its not a request limit, cuz I use it many times a day and they don't mention about any limit. "allow_url_fopen" is on. and  i cant seem to find error.log

Comment: Ok the error i have is this: HTTP Error 500 (Internal Server Error): An unexpected condition was encountered while the server was attempting to fulfill the request.

Comment: Ok i removed the web request, and it works fine. But i need the web service for the IP geolocation data, if not its useless. Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depending on restrictions on the part of GeoIP, they may be limiting the number of transactions you can submit, how many you can submit within a specific timeframe, etc. Or you could just be hitting the maximum execution time on your own server.

I think you can check your own server limit using `phpinfo()`, and, if needed (and allowed by your server admin), you can adjust it on a per-script basis using `set_time_limit()` [PHP Manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.set-time-limit.php).

If the number of rows which are processed are fluctuating, you may also find some help by tracking the time you are taking to process the rows. Adding a counter for the rows (just a simple integer which you increment with each row being handled) and using something like [this technique](http://www.developerfusion.com/code/2058/determine-execution-time-in-php/) to echo how long the script has been running as it starts each row may provide you with a better idea of when the script is failing, how long it is running for, whether longer delays per row are causing a lesser number of rows to be processed in a batch, etc.

Comment: It worked! So its the time limit on the script, thank you very much :D

Comment: Excellent. Any chance I can ask you to mark this question as Correct by clicking the checkmark beside it? That is how you close a question off, and give a bit of a reward to people who answer them for you. Cheers.